# Div Class on Flex Containers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am a beginning coder, and for my first project, I would like to create a flex containers, where two out of the three heed the same properties, and the third does not. To do this, I did the following:

```
    .flex-container1{
display: flex;
width: 75%;
float:center;
}

.flex-container1>div {
background-color: gray;
width: 75%;
height: 100%;
margin: 10px;
padding: 20px;
float: center;
}

.flex-container2{
width: 150%;
height: 100%;
margin: 5%;
background-color: white;

<div class="flex-container1">
<div>Sample 1</div>
<div class"flex-container2">Sample 2</div>
<div>Sample3</div>
</div>
```

What is a possible solution for this? Many thanks.

Comment: Please post your code here

Comment: what are you trying to do with each `div` sample 1,2,3 can explain more? do you want 1 and 2 to be on the same line ? same side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but quickly made it [Codepen flex demo](https://codepen.io/eyecandy91/pen/eVBPex?editors=1100#)

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-container--default">Sample 1</div>
  <div class="flex-container--long">Sample 2</div>
  <div class="flex-container--default">Sample3</div>
</div>

.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
}

.flex-container--default,
.flex-container--long {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.flex-container--default {
  background-color: gray;
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-container--long{
  background-color: white;
  flex: 3
}
```